# Adding a function to customized status bar in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Is there a way to add a function to the customized status bar in Excel 2007?

I want to include a subtract method next to functions such as SUM, COUNT, AVERAGE, etc.

Comment: Also, SUM, COUNT, AVERAGE, MINIMUM, and MAXIMUM are all defined when more than two cells are selected -- DIFFERENCE would not be.

Comment: Yes, I figured it was not implemented due to the cell property constraints as mentioned by @pnuts.  So I will have to find an alternate solution that could increase my worksheet productivity.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a workaround.  I took IBM's opening and closing stock prices for the month (from http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/ibm/historical) and then duplicated the data in the negative:

[image: screen shot of Excel shhet with E4 = -B4, etc.]

Now I can subtract any two numbers by selecting one and the negative of the other.  For example, IBM gained 57¢ in trading on 9/14:

[image: screen shot of same sheet with C11 and E11 (i.e., -B11) selected]

Comment: Excellent! so the hack will involve creating a macro that can convert a column to negative value?

Comment: I've been fiddling with some of the function's in Excel and found the _=IMSUB_ function which in contrast will just calculate the difference of two cells as long as they are real numbers.

It would look like this for @Scott's example:
=IMSUB(C11,B11)        

=>The output would be 0.57 only caveat is that would require another column in your workbook as oppose to the result appearing in the customized header.

Answer (score 0):

Dick Kusleika addressed this in 2004, see here:

http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/12/09/selection-stats/#comments

(look through the comments on the article too.)
A drawback with this approach is that Excel's standard status messages are no longer visible.

Comment: Interesting discussion thread.  Thank you for sharing this information with us.

Comment: And will this work for Excel 2016?